# -26![] and .Q.hg still fails even with everything installed in place

Tags: openssl, kdb

I installed `openssl` from this repository -> `https://github.com/openssl/openssl/releases/tag/OpenSSL_1_0_2g`

I followed the steps in the `INSTALL` file.

```
./config
make
make test 
sudo make install
```

`openssl` was installed in `/usr/local/ssl/`.

Trying to execute this with `openssl version` gave me an error. I set up an alias and everything worked fine. `kdb+` still gave me an error when executing `-26![]` and `.Q.hg`

I copied the files from `/usr/local/ssl/bin/` to `/usr/bin/`

Now openssl works fine when I execute `openssl version -d` but when I run `-26![]` still gives me the following error:

```
q)(-26!)[] 
'Could not initialize openssl. Error was incompatible ssl version

  [0]  (-26!)[] 
       ^
q)
```

And `.Q.hg` gives the following order:

```
q).Q.hg hsym`$"https://www.google.com"
'conn. OS reports: Protocol not available
  [0]  .Q.hg hsym`$"https://www.google.com"
       ^
q))
```

The `SSL_CA_CERT_FILE` is set to:

```
q))getenv`SSL_CA_CERT_FILE
"/home/$USER/certs/cabundle.pem"
q))
```

and the certificates have been downloaded as instructed on the `ks` website.

My architecture:

```
   Static hostname: user-X542UAR
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: 
           Boot ID: 
  Operating System: Linux Mint 19.1
            Kernel: Linux 4.15.0-20-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Output from `.z.K`:

```
q).z.K
3.6
```

Comment: Have you checked the k4 listbox/topicbox for solutions? This is the official support channel for kdb. Here's a related one for example: https://k4.topicbox.com/groups/k4/T7f1230528ba7f79d-M1c8948f1dd286e7834d74b85/could-not-initialize-openssl-error-was-incompatible-ssl-version

Comment: Are your openSSL library paths included in your LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH variables?